# c++, visual studio 2010 pointer in list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers, linked-list

I have a simple question about pointers in a list.

```
pointer* Temp2;
Temp->data = 10; //(Temp is one of the elements in a list)
```

//Now I want to use a pointer to point at this element in order to modify its data.

```
Temp2=Temp;
Temp2->data = 5;
```

Will this do the job?

Comment: What is `Temp`? is it a `pointer*`? Is the element it points to stored in a `std::list` or in some other list? What do you want to reach? Did you try it and did it work?

Comment: What is the type of Temp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as it's not a local pointer, yes, and only because it's a list. If it was a vector for example, the answer would be no, since your pointer would probably point to another element as soon as you modified the vector, while that doesn't happen with a list.

what i mean by local pointer is

```
_DATA local_data;
pointer *local_p = &local_data;
list.push_back(local_data);
```

local_p is useless now because it's pointing to the stack, and you need to get a pointer to the heap, which std::list has created for your new element.

for example

```
pointer *improved_pointer = &*list.begin();
```

now you can do

```
pointer *alias = improved_pointer;
```

and of course, both pointers will work, until you delete the element from your list container, only then it would invalidate your pointers.